# Having an express server, is it possible to communicate between react and php?

Tags: php, node.js, express, router

For example, I have the data I need at http://localhost:3000, and the data is stored in the database connected to php!

When I did something in php, I wrote the following code because I wanted to send the information to React as it is after receiving the information from the express router!

```
router.post('/member', (req, res, next)=>{
let body = '';
req.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data;
});

req.on('end', function() {
    var POST = qs.parse(body);
    console.log(POST); // { name: 'ben', foo: 'bar' }

    request.post({
            url:'https://nfts.perproject.io',
            json: POST,
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json charset=utf-8' }
        },
        (err:any, httpResponse:any, body:any) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json({ data: POST, msg: 'cannot post to example2.com' });
            }
            res.json({ data: POST });
        });
});
```

})

Currently, the router's POST variable contains data sent from php, but this data could not be sent to React.
Could you please suggest a solution or another way?

Comment: Why do you need an express API when you already have a PHP API? Why don't you fetch directly from PHP API?

Comment: From a quick look it seems like the req.end event callback is not the place to define the fetch to the php server (since the request is ended).

Comment: Specifically, a web page of php exists and a react page is created with php iframe.

It needs information about php because React makes a request first.
But I want to send post request to php without MemberId, but I am not getting the data I want because memberId is missing.

So I wanted to send information from php api to node first and receive that information from react.

Is there any other way?